# Is there a way to limit Google Sites search to only search against page titles?

Tags: google-classic-sites

If I search for e.g. "Something Awesome," I'd like the results to only include pages with "something" and "awesome" in the actual page title itself (they may also be in the page content, but must be in the title)

The site in question is a password-protected private Site on a Google Apps account, so none of the pages are included in the general Google index (and therefore a CSE wouldn't work).

Answer (score 3):

Try **`intitle:`** operator.

> The query `intitle:term` restricts results to documents containing
>   term in the title. For instance, [ [flu shot intitle:help](http://www.google.com/search?q=flu%20shot%20intitle%3ahelp) ] will
>   return documents that mention the word “help” in their titles, and
>   mention the words “flu” and “shot” anywhere in the document (title or
>   not).
>
> **Note:** There must be no space between the `intitle:` and the
>   following word.
>
> Putting `intitle:` in front of every word in your query is equivalent
>   to putting `allintitle:` at the front of your query, e.g., [
>   [intitle:google intitle:search](http://www.google.com/search?q=intitle%3agoogle%20intitle%3asearch) ] is the same as [ [allintitle:
>   google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=allintitle%3a%20google%20search) ].

In your case, you can use the following query:

[ [intitle:something intitle:awesome -something -awesome](http://www.google.com/search?q=intitle%3asomething%20intitle%3aawesome%20-something%20-awesome) ]

This makes sure your terms appear in the title but not in the page itself.

Comment: This works with general google search (at google.com) but isn't returning any results with Googles Sites search built into Google Sites.

Comment: If your site is not indexed by Google, I don't think it is quite possible.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the case, then.  It needs to be a private site, so it can't be in the Google index.  Oh well...